# Custom AOP spring boot annotation with ribbon client blocking api call with return "1"

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop, netflix-ribbon

I have really poor experience with ribbon/eureka so forgive me if this is a stupid question:

I have two different microservice both connected to a discovery server, the first one calls the second using a custom annotation that sends a request using rest template.
Custom annotation name is *PreHasAuthority*

**Controller :**

```
    @PreHasAuthority(value="[0].getProject()+'.requirements.update'")
    @PostMapping(CREATE_UPDATE_REQUIREMENT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUpdateRequirement(@Valid @RequestBody RequirementDTO requirementDTO
, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        return requirementService.createUpdateRequirement(requirementDTO, request, response);
    }
```

**Annotation interface :**

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PreHasAuthority {

    String value();
    
}
```

**Annotation implementation:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import netcomgroup.eu.service.AuthenticationService;

@Aspect
@Component
public class PreHasAuthorityServiceAspect {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @Around(value = "@annotation(PreHasAuthority)")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        PreHasAuthority preHasAuthority = method.getAnnotation(PreHasAuthority.class);
        
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String permission = preHasAuthority.value();
        ExpressionParser elParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression expression = elParser.parseExpression(permission);
        String per = (String) expression.getValue(args);
        
        String token =null;
        for(Object o : args) {
            if(o instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)o;
                token=request.getHeader("X-Auth");
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(token==null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Token not found");
        }
        
        boolean hasPerm = authenticationService.checkPermission(per,token);
        
        if(!hasPerm) 
            throw new Exception("Not Authorized");
    }
}
```

**My Ribbon configuration**

```
import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class RibbonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    IClientConfig config;

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new RoundRobinRule();
    }
}
```

**Eureka config in application properties**

```
#Eureka config
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://${registry.host:localhost}:${registry.port:8761}/eureka/
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled= true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds= 10
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds= 10
```

by calling the api from postman request is sendend correctly to the second microservice and i'm certain the return is "true".

After that the request stops before entering the *createUpdateRequirement* method and returns '1' as postman body response. No error of sort is provided.

My guess is that the problem resides within the custom annotation, cause when i remove the annotation the api call works perfectly, but i cannot understand the problem as it seems all setted up correctly to me.

Comment: Provide errors stacktraces, that should be easy for us to investigate this situation.

Comment: The main problem is that  i got no error, the api call just stops before entering into createUpdateRequirement for no reason to me.

Comment: @Peo did you debug the aspect code to see if it works as expected ? `around` method might not be proceeding to the `createUpdateRequirement` method

Comment: yes my aspect code worked as expected.
As Kriegaex pointed out, the solution was to add joinpoint.proceed() in the aspect method to continue execution. 
I also changed return type accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@Around` advice never calls `joinPoint.proceed()`. Hence, the intercepted target method will never be executed.

The second problem is that your advice method returns `void`, i.e. it will never match any method returning another type such as the `ResponseEntity<?> createUpdateRequirement(..)` method.

Besides, `around` is a reserved keyword in native AspectJ syntax. Even though it might work in annotation-driven syntax, you ought to rename your advice method to something else like `aroundAdvice` or `interceptPreHasAuthority` - whatever.

Please do read an AspectJ or Spring AOP tutorial, especially the [Spring manual's AOP chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop).

Comment: Thanks joinPoint.proceed() did the trick, thanks very much!